# how to apply inset to box shadow in tailwindcss?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

Tailwindcss docs (v3) talk about `inset box shadow` so briefly that I couldn't find out a way to apply a custom inset box-shadow to an element.
also `shadow-inner-[0px_-2px_4px_rgba(0,0,0,0.6)]` does not work.
Only the default `shadow-inner` works on the element.
Is there a way to apply a custom shadow-inner to an element? or how can I define a custom one in the `tailwind.config.js` file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When using arbitrary values in brackets, Tailwind converts the arbitrary value directly to a CSS property, replacing underscores with spaces. So, to define an arbitrary inset box shadow, we can simply use:

`shadow-[inset_0_-2px_4px_rgba(0,0,0,0.6)]`

This will become the CSS property:

`box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)`

Comment: one thing to note, make sure there are zero spaces. my setup wasn't working and I realized i had spaces between the commas. once i got rid of them it worked perfectly.